# Wordpress Taxonomy title output

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to output the title of a taxonomy page when viewing it.

So like, if I was on a 'tag' page I would go:

```
<?php if (is_tag()) {?>
    <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

But how would I achieve the same thing for if the user is viewing a specific taxonomy page?

`is_taxonomy()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What are you referring to specifically when you say Taxonomy? In WordPress you have pages, posts, categories, tags, and search result pages.

Comment: Hi this is what i'm using: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/06/custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-28

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this answer for anyone else wondering.

Follow this guide: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/06/04/using-custom-taxonomies-to-create-a-movie-database

Right down the bottom, the line wanted was:

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); echo $term->name; ?>
```

Comment: Ah ha, gotcha. Yea, this is in WordPress 3.0, which I haven't messed with yet. Glad you found your answer!

Answer (score 7):

can be done superdupereasy with:

```
<?php echo get_queried_object()->name; //output $taxonomy->$tax the simple way ?>
```

`name`, when beeing on some custom taxonomy page, will be the taxonomy term., e.g. on something like `example.com/books/Fiction`, this will echo `fiction`.

Instead of `name` you could also use `taxonomy`, which will echo `books`.

And shortly spoken, taxonomies are NOT categories or pages or comments, they are something you declare, like "products" or "books". Using that you unlock WordPress'es Custom Post Type functionality. You can make your own `archive-products.php`, `page-products.php`, `single-products.php` and have big fun with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example, which modifies the title only for taxonomy listing pages, using the function `is_tax()`

```
<title><?php
  global $page, $paged, $post;
  if (is_tax()) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $term_title = $term->name;
    echo "$term_title | ";
  } else {
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
  }

  // Add the blog name.
  bloginfo( 'name' );

  // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
  $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
  if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

  // Add a page number if necessary:
  if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

  ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [single_term_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_term_title) function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy enough to use the single_cat_title() function.

[See here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title) for more details.